# How to change data type in PostgresSQL on Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, ddl

I am trying to change data types from varchar to bigint on Amazon Redshift without any luck.

I have tried several syntaxes but none of them seem to work and internet is always an enormous resource of it yet I managed to not run any of it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, 'alarm_id')
FROM alarm_item;

SELECT CONVERT(alarm_id AS INT8)
FROM alarm_item;

SELECT CAST(alarm_id AS BIGINT)
FROM alarm_item;


ALTER TABLE alarm_item
    ALTER COLUMN alarm_id TYPE BIGINT;

ALTER COLUMNalarm_id TYPE BIGINT
FROM alarm_item;

ALTER TABLE alarm_item
ALTER COLUMN alarm_id TYPE INT 
USING alarm_id::integer;
```

This community has helped me on my first ever question while doing python project. So perhaps good souls would come to this question's rescue yet again.

Comment: Do you receive an error when you use `ALTER TABLE`? Can you tell us the error message?

Answer (score 0):

From [ALTER TABLE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html):

> `ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type`
> A clause that changes the size of a column defined as a VARCHAR data type.

Therefore, it would appear that it is not possible to change the type of a column (aside from changing the length of a VARCHAR column).

Instead, you could:

- Add another column
- Use `UPDATE` to set the column value based on an existing column
- Delete the original column
- Rename the new column to the name of the old column

Comment: Hi John, I tried to do the last instructions but I encountered this error: ERROR: Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647) Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647) code: 1207 context: Value: '2384228315', Character: '5' query: 16772 location: :0 process: query0_127_16772 [pid=0] ----------------------------------------------- [ErrorId: 1-63f76f35-284b892752764d8f4487fb8c]

Comment: That error is suggesting that the number was being converted to `INT`, not `BIGINT`. Please show the command you were using -- presumably for the UPDATE command?